# How often is FuelSDK for C# updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

The idea of an SDK to wrap the Soap and Rest APIs in one place is great, but looking at the fuel sdk for c#, it hasnt been updated in a very long while, and it doesnt appear to have a lot of activity in github.  What should be my expectations on how often the fuelSDK for C# is updated, and when it will have new features?  For example, the java and php fuel sdks allow you to create profile attributes, yet the c# one does not, it just lets you update existing ones.  They appear to be more robust than the c# sdk.